# Socks5 proxy works for browser but not Nodejs

Tags: node.js, socks

EDIT: There's an additional issue with the address I'm trying to reach. Until that's resolved, this question is moot for me. Leaving it up for discussion only.

I have two macbooks, personal and work. My work mac has a VPN connection to my company network that is tied to the hardware itself, so I can't simply use the same credentials on my personal mac.

To access my company intranet at https://intranet.mycompany.com from my personal mac, I first ssh to my work mac from my personal mac:

```
ssh my-username@work-mac.local -D 9999
```

then turn on Socks proxy for wifi in the Network system preference pane on my personal mac. I have the proxy server set to `localhost:9999`.

From there, I can access the intranet in my browser on my personal mac.

There's an REST endpoint on the intranet that I want to access from a node script on my personal mac. For example:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const response = await fetch('https://intranet.mycompany.com/api/todos/');
const body = await response.text();
```

but that results in `ENOTFOUND intranet.mycompany.com`.

I've also tried using [socks-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-socks-proxy-agent) following their example like so:

```
const url = require('url');
const https = require('https');
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent');

const proxy = 'socks://localhost:9999';
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

const endpoint = 'https://intranet.mycompany.com/api/todos/';
console.log('attempting to GET %j', endpoint);
const opts = url.parse(endpoint);

const agent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxy);
opts.agent = agent;

https.get(opts, function (res) {
    console.log('"response" event!', res.headers);
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

but also get `ENOTFOUND intranet.mycompany.com`. And in any case, what I really want is to just send *all* outbound traffic through the proxy without having to specify the endpoint each time.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

socks-proxy-agent just enable dns lookup from socks5:// not socks:// or socks5h://
So, maybe you could change your proxy url to socks5://xxxxxxxxx so maybe everythings will work just fine.

Comment: Van Chung thanks but that didn't work. Still `ENOTFOUND`